# Нужна ли запятая после слов "благодаря ей"?

Tags: пунктуация

Именно благодаря ей (?) эконометристам удается проверять теоретические модели на практических данных.

Answer (score 2):

**Именно благодаря ей эконометристам удается проверять теоретические модели на практических данных.**

(Как вариант: Именно благодаря ей эконометристам удается проверять теоретические модели **на практике**).

В общем случае обстоятельственные обороты с производными предлогами (БЛАГОДАРЯ, СОГЛАСНО  и др.) **обособляются факультативно**, что определяется структурой предложения и распространенностью оборота.

В данном случае мы имеем **нераспространенный оборот**, а при наличии **наречия ИМЕННО** он практически всегда входит в основной состав предложения и не обособляется.

Но исключения возможны по уже указанным причинам (распространенный оборот не вписывается в структуру предложения, требуется наличие паузы), например:

**Именно благодаря своему пограничному положению**, такие, например, органы индивида, как движение, действие, образ, слово, имеют и свое внешнее, и свое внутреннее (В. П. Зинченко  «Вопросы психологии», 2004.10.12).

**Именно благодаря его вводу в эксплуатацию,** Газпром получил выигрыш во времени для разворота работ по обустройству месторождений Ямала. [ «Газовая промышленность», 2004.10.25]

Распространенные обороты **без наречия ИМЕННО** обособляются чаще (по структуре и функции они напоминают придаточные предложения):

**Благодаря большому количеству отделений и длительному периоду исторического развития,** почтовые ведомства обладают поистине глобальной досягаемостью практически в любой стране [«Вопросы статистики», 2004]

Answer (score 0):

Корректно:

**Именно благодаря ей эконометристам удается проверять теоретические модели на практических данных.**

Слово "благодаря" может выступать не только в качестве деепричастия, но и в качестве предлога (глагольное значение утрачено). В этом случае конструкции с  предлогом "благодаря" не выделяются запятыми (за некоторыми исключениями, которые мы здесь рассматривать не будем).

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

**Именно благодаря баблосу магический червь и сохраняет свое бессмертие.** 
Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013)

**Именно благодаря такому механизму у инфицированных грызунов I/ LnJ рождается здоровое потомство.** Алла Солодова. Универсальным механизм защиты от СПИДа существует // «Детали мира», 2011